# Django template isn't displaying some model object attributes on the page but will display others

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm following a tutorial on Real Python to create a very simple portfolio website.
https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/

I've created a Project model:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.FilePathField(path="/img")
```

I've added a number of different objects/projects to this model in the shell and saved them. Here is the HTML for the web page I'm displaying them on:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_content %}
<h1>Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static project.image %}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ project.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'project_detail' project.pk %}" class="btn-primary">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I'm displaying them on cards that are added using a for loop that iterates every time a new object is created. On this page, the project title, description and read more button are displaying correctly but for some reason the image is not. I have the images placed in a /static/img folder in the same directory as the app 'projects'. And I've tried re-entering the object data, using PNGs, JPEGs etc. but none of these seem to get the images to display correctly.

Next, the 'in detail' page is loaded when the read more button is clicked. Here is the HTML for that:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block page_content %}
<h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <img src="{% static project.image %}" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>About the project:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
        <br>
        <h5>Technology used:</h5>
        <p>{{ project.technology }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

On this page, not only does the image not load, but the project title, description and technology used don't display either. Only a blank space where the image should be and the h5 text shown above is displayed.

I've been following the tutorial as exact as I can and only making small aesthetic changes here and there. I've been through the source code on github and compared my code directly to the authors code and the core components all seem to be exactly the same. Am I missing something?

*ADDITIONAL INFO*

settings.py static files:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/img/'
```

views.py for the 'projects' app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from projects.models import Project

def project_index(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {
        'projects': projects
    }
    return render(request, 'project_index.html', context)

def project_detail(request, pk):
    projects = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'projects': projects
    }
    return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: In your settings.py have you specified the correct path to your images folder? STATIC_URL = 'static/img'

Comment: I feel like here are multiple things to adress. For the image: I'd like to see the part of your `settings.py` file where you define `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`.
For the other site, where some context does not load, I'd like to see your corresponding view in `views.py`. Without I suppose it will be hard to help

Comment: Hi guys, the additional info you requested has been added to the post. Cheers!